# Navigation drawer with other component

Tags: java, android

How can use navigation drawer with an other component?

My activity_main is

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ListView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="262dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >  

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/..."
    />
...
</LinearLayout>
```

With this xml file I want to add navigation drawer in my App.

Comment: Do you mean you want each navigation drawer `ListView` item to have a button? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: i have some buttons and layaout  in activiy_main

 with this views( button and etc) i want to add navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >  

        <!-- your buttons and whatever else is in your main layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

To initialize the drawer, in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close)
       {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // Deal with the selection
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To handle click events for your navigation drawer, see [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks).

To listen for open and close events of the navigation drawer, see [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#OpenClose).